# How to maintain input field focused before & after jQuery ThickBox

Tags: jquery, focus, thickbox

Consider the scenario :

I have Search form on having address,city,state and image link base search button. on click on search button OR pressing enter in any text box, javascript validates the input parameters. If anything is found wrong it shows the custom message in jQuery Thickbox.

Question : For example I entered wrong zip code and pressed enter. It shows message thickbox (no buttons in it). Pressing escape or space in it closes it down. I want to maintain the focus on zipcode text (last element having focus) even after thickbox is closed so I can correct zip code now.

Is there any event listener or something which helps here for before opening and after closing events of thickbox ?

How to do this ?

Comment: Look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091998/how-would-you-trigger-an-event-when-a-thickbox-closes

Comment: @VincentLITUR already tried that before posting this. It totally fails in this scenario.